# Fix issue regarding session user only being able to send one image file ever

Tags: php, image, session

My website should allow for users to upload an share images.
Well a session user must be able to insert as many images as they want, however I've only allowed them to insert one image at a time. The problem is that a session user can only send one picture, ever. So even if they log out and then back in again, they wont be able to insert another image. What i'm trying to find out is that, how can i make it that a session user can keep inserting images one after another without any issues. Baring in mind that i'm not actually sending the image file to the database, i send the image to a server folder where then the image file path is then saved to the database. Thanks. my database table where the images are stored have headers of ImageID, UserID and Image.  Here is the code:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "Images Upload/" . md5($_FILES["image"]["name"]))){
    $target= "Images Upload/".md5($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $sessionid= $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $query= "insert into images(UserID, Image) values('$sessionid','$target')";

    if(mysql_query($query)){
        echo"<script>alert('Upload Successful!')</script>";
        }
        else{echo "<script>alert('Image can't be sent!')</script>";}
    }
    else{echo "<script>alert('An error has occured!')</script>";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `USERID` in your database is set as primary key, which it shouldn't if you want them to be able to upload more than one image.

Simply connect to your mysql server and remove that primary key thing on UserID and it should be fine.